# Three-way comparison operator with inconsistent ordering deduction

Tags: c++, qt, c++20, return-type-deduction, spaceship-operator

Some time ago I defined my first three-way comparison operator. It compared a single type and replaced multiple conventional operators. Great feature. Then I tried to implement a similar operator for comparing two variants by delegation:

```
auto operator <=> (const QVariant& l, const QVariant& r)
{   
   switch (l.type())
   {
      case QMetaType::Int:
         return l.toInt() <=> r.toInt();
      case QMetaType::Double:
         return l.toDouble() <=> r.toDouble();
      default:
         throw;
   }
}
```

This doesn't compile, I get the error

> inconsistent deduction for auto return type: ‘std::strong_ordering’ and then ‘std::partial_ordering’.

Obviously `int` and `double` spaceship operators return different types.

What is the correct way to solve this?

Comment: Doesn't `<=>` need to behave symmetrical? By switching on only `l.type()` you violate that property.

Comment: @Bergi You are right. This is why in my real code I am checking for equality of types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The types of the `operator<=>` for `int` and `double` differ but they should have a common type. You probably want to leverage the compiler in automatically finding the proper type. You *could* use `std::common_type` to do but that would be quite ugly. It is easier to just leverage what `std::common_type` type does under the (when implemented in the library rather the compiler) and use the ternary operator:

```
auto operator <=> (const QVariant& l, const QVariant& r)
{   
    return l.type() == QMetaType:Int? l.toInt() <=> r.toInt()
         : l.type() == QMetaType::Double? l.toDouble() <=> r.toDouble()
         : throw;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a brilliant solution for two types. But well, my real life function will have dozens of types. That will be a mess, right?

Comment: @Silicomancer: how so? You need to list your types and how to extract them anyway and I already set you how to make multiple cases be read easily. If you area so inclined you _could_ put the logic into a variadic function where you effectively spell out the type to accessor-lmbda finction and have the logic there but it would just break down to the same stuff

Comment: Royally inclined, yes ;-) Hm, using a variadic function came to my mind as well. I guess that could be an even better solution.

Comment: @Silicomancer depends on how you spin it, actually. Just for this use-case it would be more typing and obfuscation. If you have a suitable binary `apply()` function which take the operation (in this case `[](auto const& l, auto const& r)( return l <=> r; }`) as argument, it could be kind of nice: `return apply(op, l, r);` However, writing `apply()` is a bit annoying albeit mechanical.

Comment: Have a look at my answer, what do you think?

Comment: @Silicomancer Interesting - I don’t use Qt so I don’t know the interface. It actually seems to be a closed set if types whose choices are accessible by `value<T>()`: in that case a fairly generic implement is, indeed, possibe: I had assumed you’d need to map things via `toInt()`, `toDouble()`, etc. (which should have caused me to realize that it must be closed). I think you could avoid the need of `common_type` by still using the ternary in the recursion and using the `std::strong_order` for the termination.

Comment: It isn't actually a closed set. It can be extended during compile time using an old style macro. The toXxx() functions are available for most (all?) of the built-in types only. value() can be used anyway but is required for user types.

Answer (score 22):

Same way you resolve any other function which returns `auto` in which different `return` statements deduce differently. You either:

1. Ensure that all the `return`s have the same type, or
2. Explicitly pick a return type.

In this case, `int`s compare as `strong_ordering` while `double`s compare as `partial_ordering`, and `strong_ordering` is implicitly convertible to `partial_ordering`, you can do either:

```cpp
std::partial_ordering operator <=>(const QVariant& l, const QVariant& r) {
    // rest as before
}
```

or explicitly cast the integer comparison:

```cpp
      case QMetaType::Int:
         return std::partial_ordering(l.toInt() <=> r.toInt());
```

That gives you a function returning `partial_ordering`.

---

If you want to return `strong_ordering` instead, you have to lift the `double` comparison to a higher category. You can do that in two ways:

You can use `std::strong_order`, which is a more expensive operation, but provides a total ordering over all floating point values. You would then write:

```cpp
      case QMetaType::Double:
         return std::strong_order(l.toDouble(), r.toDouble());
```

Or you can do something like consider `NaN`s ill-formed and throw them out somehow:

```cpp
      case QMetaType::Double: {
         auto c = l.toDouble() <=> r.toDouble();
         if (c == std::partial_ordering::unordered) {
             throw something;
         } else if (c == std::partial_ordering::less) {
            return std::strong_ordering::less;
         } else if (c == std::partial_ordering::equivalent) {
            return std::strong_ordering::equal;
         } else {
            return std::strong_ordering::greater;
         }
      }
```

It's more tedious but I'm not sure if there's a more direct way to do this kind of lifting.

Comment: Does `std::strong_order` have a performance cost over your last suggestion in the cases where the partial ordering can be simply converted to a corresponding strong ordering? That is, are those three cases the same thing that `std::strong_order` does for those cases? (There might still be reasons to throw on unordered results if you consider such values ill-formed and want to fail fast, so it’s a good suggestion either way, but I’m trying to understand the options a little better.)

Comment: @KRyan Yes. `std::strong_order` actually does provide a total order over floating points, including all the `NaN`s (this is ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559 `totalOrder`). That's surely more work than the branching -- but it's also very different behavior.

Comment: I understand that, but I was asking specifically about those branches where it is the same. It seems like those branches should be the same, and performance should be the same if the values would use those branches, no?

Comment: @KRyan I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Wondering, std::strong_order(double, double ); does not compile on g++ 11 w. std=c++20. Is there no implementation for a strong_ordering of floats in g++ ?

Answer (score 0):

I played around with some template code to implement Dietmar Kühls idea of using `std::common_type`. This is the result example code:

```
template <typename CommonT, typename... ArgsT> requires (sizeof...(ArgsT) == 0)
inline CommonT variantSpaceshipHelper([[maybe_unused]] const QVariant& pLeft, [[maybe_unused]] const QVariant& pRight) noexcept
{
   std::terminate(); // Variant type does not match any of the given template types
}

template <typename CommonT, typename T, typename... ArgsT>
inline CommonT variantSpaceshipHelper(const QVariant& pLeft, const QVariant& pRight) noexcept
{
   if (pLeft.type() == static_cast<QVariant::Type>(qMetaTypeId<T>()))
   {
      return (pLeft.value<T>() <=> pRight.value<T>());
   }

   return variantSpaceshipHelper<CommonT, ArgsT...>(pLeft, pRight);
}

template <typename... ArgsT>
inline auto variantSpaceship(const QVariant& pLeft, const QVariant& pRight) noexcept
{
   using CommonT = std::common_type_t<decltype(std::declval<ArgsT>() <=> std::declval<ArgsT>())...>;
   return variantSpaceshipHelper<CommonT, ArgsT...>(pLeft, pRight);
}

inline auto operator <=>(const QVariant& pLeft, const QVariant& pRight) noexcept
{
   assert(pLeft.type() == pRight.type());
   return variantSpaceship<int, double>(pLeft, pRight);
}
```

Additional types can easily be added to the `variantSpaceship` call.